# Indexing vs Reverse-indexing

Tags: python, indexing

I have a very simple question: Which is better, Indexing or Reverse Indexing?

For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
print list1[-1]
print list1[len(list1) - 1]
```

Now both print statement prints the same thing but does this mean that both expressions are same?

- How are they evaluated when the code is executed ?
- Does using reverse indexing (`list1[-1]`) gives a performance advantage over indexing (`list1[len(list1) - 1]`) or is it the other way around?

Comment: `print list1[-1]` is better

Comment: How could `len(list1) - 1` *possibly* be faster than `-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, independent of any performance considerations, it's pretty clear that `list1[-1]` is the proper way to do it. It's concise, easy-to-read, and directly expresses your intent.

That said, here are some timings:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [random.randint(1, 20) for _ in range(20000)]

%timeit list1[-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 51.6 ns per loop
%timeit list1[len(list1)-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 146 ns per loop

%timeit list2[-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 52.4 ns per loop
%timeit list2[len(list1)-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 148 ns per loop
```

It's pretty obvious why `list1[-1]` is faster. First, there's no real difference between list indexing and negative list indexing. The dominant performance concern there is the indexing, not a small conversion.

```
%timeit list2[-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 52.4 ns per loop
%timeit list2[19999]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 47.1 ns per loop
```

So both versions have to do one list index that takes about the same amount of time, but one of them also has to extract the length first and perform subtraction, which are non-trivial at these scales.

```
%timeit len(list2)
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 71 ns per loop
% timeit 20000 - 1
# 100000000 loops, best of 3: 14.9 ns per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Can you please describe how the compiler reads both statements? Like for example compiler knows the memory address of `list1` and then if I want to print `list1[1]` it will just access the memory address next to `list1` and so on... so how does compiler evaluate `list1[-1]`?

Comment: Python's source code is [publicly available](https://github.com/python/cpython). In particular, I'm guessing [this file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) contains the details you want.

Answer (score 3):

Surely `print list1[-1]` is better and more **[pythonic](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)** because in `print list1[len(list1) - 1]` you call `len` function and it has a lower performance than first print !

see the real time of both : clearly you can see the difference !

Note that **sys is The system CPU time that the program used. This includes only the kernel system calls and not any user library calls.**

```
~/Desktop $ time python -c print  list1[len[1,2,3] - 1]


real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.004s
~/Desktop $ time python -c print  list1[-1]


real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

**real** is The total elapsed time between start and end of the program.

**user** is The user CPU time that the program used. This includes all user mode library calls that the program made.

Comment: Why is `list1[len[1,2,3] - 1] sys 0m0.004s` < `list1[-1] sys     0m0.008s`??

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi `sys` means how long the program has spent in the kernel land. The `time` output includes the python interpreter startup etc, which is a really meaningless way of profiling such short code.

Comment: sys is The system CPU time that the program used. This includes only the kernel system calls and not any user library calls.